# Huawei Ascend P1 U9200: rooting

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, rooting, stock-android, huawei

I own a **Huawei Ascend P1** smartphone (**U9200, unlocked, international version**, still original Android 4.0.3 factory build B003). During about a year that I have the phone, it started being **much slower** and I decided that it's time to upgrade the software. Before I will embark on that journey, I want to backup my information using *Titanium Backup*. However, as you know, it requires *root* permissions. Therefore, I have the following questions for you today:

1) Could you point me to **verified (trusted!) instructions on rooting** this particular phone? I found these instructions on the XDA site, but they talk about rooting P1 with Android 4.1.1, so not sure, if it's safe to proceed: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2450306.

2) Do I need to separately **unlock bootloader** (S-OFF) and, if yes, could you point to verified instructions for P1?

**Your advice will be very much appreciated!**

Comment: URL for the P1's B315 build: http://en.ui.vmall.com/downloadp1.html. URL for the P1's CM 11 build: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528822.

Comment: This site works best with ***one question asked per post***. With so many questions in one, people either are afraid answering when they can't answer all, or the resulting answers become "messy" to follow. I'd recommend you to split your questions: 1+2 belong together, 3 is a separate one, as is 4. 5 will probably be closed as being "too broad", unless you can give some more details of what *specifically* you're after.

Comment: @Izzy: Thank you for your advice - it makes total sense. I will split the original post, when I get a chance. P.S. Sorry, don't have enough reputation yet to upvote, will do that later.